# Puppeteer not a valid selector

Tags: puppeteer

I am attempting to use puppeteer to scrape the information pre-loaded into an input box. I believe that would mean it is the placeholder.

I cannot seem to get the selector to work. I right click in the input box and copy selector using chrome dev tools and I get `#company-legal-name > span > ng-transclude > wf:textfield > div > input`

But if I put this into the console

```js
document.querySelector('#company-legal-name > span > ng-transclude > wf:textfield > div > input')
```

I get this error

```
VM637:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#company-legal-name > span > ng-transclude > wf:textfield > div > input' is not a valid selector.
at <anonymous>:1:10
```

I have tried many different things but it can never locate the selector. The page appears to be in angular if that makes a difference. Unfortunately, I can't link the page as it's locked to non-admin.

PS:

```js
document.getElementById('#company-legal-name')
```

returns `null`

Answer (score 2):

`wf:textfield` is not a valid CSS selector, hence you get a syntax error:

```js
> document.querySelector('wf:textfield')
SyntaxError: 'wf:textfield' is not a valid selector
```

whereas without the `wf:` it is accepted:

```js
>document.querySelector('textfield')
null
```

I also have doubts about the `ng-transclude` selector, which I guess is supposed to be a (Angular?) tag name.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I am now not getting any error but I am still getting null.. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you maybe strip down and attach the HTML document to your question? It only needs to contain the nodes in the path you want to match/select. Please remember that CSS selector `A > B` only works if `B` is a *direct* child of `A`, i.e. `.a > .b` will match `<A class="a"><B class="b">...</B></A>` but not `<A class="a"><B><C class="b">...</C></B></A>`

Answer (score 2):

- You are getting invalid selector because of the colon (:), specifically `wf:textfield` is not a valid selector for querySelector even if you get it using inspect element.
- `getElementById` will require you to remove the hash in front of the selector`#`

Solution:
Remove the broken piece (`wf:textfield`), and write like this,

`#company-legal-name input`

Looks like we can also use `input[name="input_2"]` as discussed in the comments.

Comment: Thank you  `document.querySelector('#company-legal-name > span > ng-transclude > div > input')` does return null! Any idea how I pull the info from the input instead of getting null?

Comment: What does `document.querySelector('#company-legal-name')` return?

Comment: https://imgur.com/PBBfBBB the placeholder text I'm looking for isn't anywhere in there

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `input[name="input_2"]` as the selector? It seems very reasonable one. Try `#company-legal-name input` and `input[name="input_2"]`, whichever works. It just have to be unique, that's all.